# Luxand OpenIPVideoCamera returns -15

Tags: c#, face-detection, ip-camera

I am using Luxand Library as a face detection for my application.
I can open the webcam but when i want to open an ip camera with **FSDKCam.OpenIPVideoCamera()** method, it returns **-15** and camera does not open.

I tested the url with VLC and everything was ok. 
Does anybody have experience with this problem?

Comment: The error indicates it didn't connect (https://www.luxand.com/facesdk/documentation/errorcodes.php).  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the VLC results and your application results and compare the HTTP header to see differences.

Answer (score 0):

hi you cant use rtsp you must use mjpeg stream also you must provide video stream cgi luxand face sdk support mjpeg stream only to know your camera is support mjpeg if not find on specification try open a ip camera from browser then press f 12 and click element on camera if found video.cgi on url you camera is support mjpeg and you can get url from this website https://www.foscam.com/faqs/view.html?id=128
or 
https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=china
note : on url you can support your username and password and port forget about add it sprite on textbox filed just add a full url on ip filed 
example 
http://192.168.1.100:26239/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=888888
 after you sure your camera support mjpeg stream you can also with face sdk use difrent way to display your camera 
go to this website https://ip-webcam.appspot.com/ and download this app after download add your camera url wish is support cgi and mjpeg 
example 
http://192.168.1.100:26239/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=888888
note some camera not support full url you have to add only 
http://192.168.1.100:26239/
then add your username and password 
in next filed 
next step you must change on camera list on example your camera number for example if your fron camera int number for it 1 you must change it to 2 or 0 it is up of your device 
  cameraName = cameraList[2];//1//2//0
play on that number to know  your ip camera number 
am sure that will help you and am sure you get a right answer 
best regard 
ibrahim ali 
mam